# Check whether Tensorflow is running on GPU

Tags: tensorflow

[image]I have read many questions and "guides" on how to understand if Tensorflow is running on GPU but I am still quite confused.

I have taken a screenshot of my session and I would like to understand what is going on, and if Tensorflow is running on GPU or CPU.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Roberto, try this

```py
import tensorflow as tf
if tf.test.gpu_device_name():
    print('Default GPU Device: {}'.format(tf.test.gpu_device_name()))
else:
    print("Please install GPU version of TF")
```

the output should be

```py
Default GPU Device: /device:GPU:0
```

GPU 0 is your GTX 860m

Comment: Thanks, I am getting `Please install GPU version of TF` with some other log info. But I have already installed tensorflow gpu, would you like to have a look at the screenshot?

Comment: please open you Tensorflow environment in the console and type
```python
pip list
```
Then take a screenshot of all packages.

Comment: Seemed like a restart solved the issue, sorry for wasting your time but thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: Same for you! Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

try

```
 tf.debugging.set_log_device_placement(True)
```

then run something from tensorflow like

```
a = tf.constant([1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0], shape=[2, 3], name='a')
b = tf.constant([1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0], shape=[3, 2], name='b')
c = tf.matmul(a, b)
```

then the console will print the device tf is running on
[image]