# Tensorflow isn't using gpu

Tags: tensorflow

I got into Deep Learning and Computer Vision through a Youtube Video and started programming and installed TensorFlow and TensorFlow GPU (also installed cuda and cudnn). To check if it was using my GPU I googled and saw this report: [Check whether Tensorflow is running on GPU](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55691174/check-whether-tensorflow-is-running-on-gpu) and ran the code. Here is my output:

> > > import tensorflow as tf
> > > 2021-07-03 10:53:12.843163: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53] Successfully opened dynamic library cudart64_110.dll
> > > if tf.test.gpu_device_name():
> > > ...     print('Default GPU Device: {}'.format(tf.test.gpu_device_name()))
> > > ... else:
> > > ...     print("Please install GPU version of TF")
> > > ...
> > > 2021-07-03 10:53:36.416599: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:142] This TensorFlow binary is optimized with oneAPI Deep Neural Network Library (oneDNN) to use the following CPU instructions in performance-critical operations:  AVX AVX2
> > > To enable them in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
> > > 2021-07-03 10:53:36.421369: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53] Successfully opened dynamic library nvcuda.dll
> > > 2021-07-03 10:53:36.461645: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1733] Found device 0 with properties:
> > > pciBusID: 0000:01:00.0 name: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 2060 computeCapability: 7.5
> > > coreClock: 1.2GHz coreCount: 30 deviceMemorySize: 6.00GiB deviceMemoryBandwidth: 245.91GiB/s
> > > 2021-07-03 10:53:36.461807: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53] Successfully opened dynamic library cudart64_110.dll
> > > 2021-07-03 10:53:36.465569: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'cublas64_11.dll'; dlerror: cublas64_11.dll not found
> > > 2021-07-03 10:53:36.467869: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'cublasLt64_11.dll'; dlerror: cublasLt64_11.dll not found
> > > 2021-07-03 10:53:36.470114: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'cufft64_10.dll'; dlerror: cufft64_10.dll not found
> > > 2021-07-03 10:53:36.472643: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'curand64_10.dll'; dlerror: curand64_10.dll not found
> > > 2021-07-03 10:53:36.474775: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'cusolver64_11.dll'; dlerror: cusolver64_11.dll not found
> > > 2021-07-03 10:53:36.476926: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'cusparse64_11.dll'; dlerror: cusparse64_11.dll not found
> > > 2021-07-03 10:53:36.478093: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53] Successfully opened dynamic library cudnn64_8.dll
> > > 2021-07-03 10:53:36.478147: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1766] Cannot dlopen some GPU libraries. Please make sure the missing libraries mentioned above are installed properly if you would like to use GPU. Follow the guide at https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu for how to download and setup the required libraries for your platform.
> > > Skipping registering GPU devices...
> > > 2021-07-03 10:53:36.591753: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1258] Device interconnect StreamExecutor with strength 1 edge matrix:
> > > 2021-07-03 10:53:36.591877: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1264]      0
> > > 2021-07-03 10:53:36.593445: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1277] 0:   N
> > > Please install GPU version of TF

As I mentioned earlier, I already installed it. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: The reason is explained in that error message: you don't have the CUDA libraries in your PATH, e.g. "**Could not load dynamic library 'cublas64_11.dll'; dlerror: cublas64_11.dll not found**"

Comment: Did you try following the link in the error message and following the steps there?

Comment: Yes I followed the steps there. I already looked at it before. I have cuda 10.2 11.4 and 10.0 installed. Should I delete the 10.2 and 10.0 version?

Comment: It is recognizing my gpu, but isnt using it, when I run this:                               print("Num GPUs Available: ", len(tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU')))                    
 It prints out: Num GPUs Available:  1